# solving a for loop with stream

Tags: java-stream

I solved this rather easy task where given is a list containing a list containing a list and so on.
Using for loops its pretty easy to get the desired info but I just can´t wrap my hea around how to solve the same with a stream. Since I read a lot about how easy streams are I wanted to use this to practise them but I guess I haven´t fully understood them yet.
Please help me and explain how to solve the same task.
Working for loop looks like this:

```
    public Product getProduct(@RequestParam Long productId,@RequestParam Long colorId) {

    Optional<ProductResource> product = productService.findProduct(productId);

    List<ProductVariantResource> variantResources = product.get().getVariants();
    ProductVariantResource selectedVariantResource = null;
    ProductColorResource selectedColorResource = null;
    Long lowestPrice = 999999999999L;
    String lowestPriceCurrency = null;


    for (ProductVariantResource variantResource : variantResources) {
        List<ProductColorResource> colorResources = variantResource.getColors();
        for (ProductColorResource productColorResource : colorResources) {
            if (productColorResource.getId().equals(colorId)) {
                selectedVariantResource = variantResource;
                selectedColorResource = productColorResource;
                List<ProductSizeResource> sizeResources = productColorResource.getSizes();
                for (ProductSizeResource productSizeResource : sizeResources) {
                    if (lowestPrice > productSizeResource.getPrice().getValue()){
                        lowestPrice = productSizeResource.getPrice().getValue();
                        lowestPriceCurrency = productSizeResource.getPrice().getCurrency();
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    String productName = product.get().getName();
    String selectedColorName = selectedColorResource.getName();
    Long selectedVariantId = selectedVariantResource.getId();
    String selectedVariantName = selectedVariantResource.getName();
    BigDecimal price = new BigDecimal(lowestPrice).movePointLeft(2);
    String bestPrice = "ab "+ lowestPriceCurrency + " " + price;
    String lastPrice = bestPrice.replace(".",",");
    Product foundProduct = new Product(productId, productName, selectedVariantId, selectedVariantName, colorId, selectedColorName, lastPrice);

    return foundProduct;
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure you are missing a matching `}` for the line `if (productColorResource.getId().equals(colorId)) {`

Comment: yeah I deleted a few lines to compromise the for just to post it here. the for loop is working perfectly its just that i want the exact same functionality as a stream

Comment: next time if code does not quite fit in a post either consider making a minimal reproducible example (also helps the answerers) or pasting it on pastebin and providing the link here.

Comment: Also I think one of the reasons you are having trouble converting your code is that your code itself is hard to maintain or read. It seems to be doing multiple things at once in the loop. I would recommend splitting things out into multiple functions if you arrive at this level of nesting (for in for in for in for). But I'll take a look

Comment: One more question: is the id of a color resource unique?

Comment: yes the id is unique

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it:

```java
class VariantWithColor { // this class should be outside of your Controller. If you are on a modern java version this can be a record instead
        private ProductVariantResource productVariantResource;
        private ProductColorResource productColorResource;

        public VariantWithColor(ProductVariantResource productVariantResource, ProductColorResource productColorResource) {
            this.productVariantResource = productVariantResource;
            this.productColorResource = productColorResource;
        }

        public ProductVariantResource getProductVariantResource() {
            return productVariantResource;
        }

        public ProductColorResource getProductColorResource() {
            return productColorResource;
        }
}



    public Product getProduct(@RequestParam Long productId,@RequestParam Long colorId) {

        ProductResource product = productService.findProduct(productId).get();

        VariantWithColor selectedVariantAndColor = product.getVariants()
                .stream()
                .flatMap(vr -> vr
                        .getColors()
                        .stream()
                        .map(cr -> new VariantWithColor(vr, cr)))
                .filter(vc -> Objects.equals(vc.getProductColorResource().getId(), colorId))
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow(); // throw exception if no element exists

        var lowestPrice = selectedVariantAndColor
                .getProductColorResource()
                .getSizes()
                .stream()
                .map(ProductSizeResource::getPrice)
                .min((a,b) -> (int) (a.getValue() - b.getValue()))
                //could also use: .min(Comparator.comparingLong(Price::getValue)) which is more declarative
                .orElseThrow();

        ProductColorResource selectedColorResource = selectedVariantAndColor.getProductColorResource();
        ProductVariantResource selectedVariantResource = selectedVariantAndColor.getProductVariantResource();

        String productName = product.getName();
        String selectedColorName = selectedColorResource.getName();
        Long selectedVariantId = selectedVariantResource.getId();
        String selectedVariantName = selectedVariantResource.getName();
        BigDecimal price = new BigDecimal(lowestPrice.getValue()).movePointLeft(2);
        String bestPrice = "ab "+ lowestPrice.getCurrency() + " " + price;
        String lastPrice = bestPrice.replace(".",",");

        return new Product(productId, productName, selectedVariantId, selectedVariantName, colorId, selectedColorName, lastPrice);
    }
```

The 2 most important transformations in streams (in my opinion):

`map`: if you have a `List<A>` and a function that takes an A and gives a B, you can create a `List<B>`.

`filter`: if you have a `List<A>` and a function that takes an A and gives a boolean you can create a smaller `List<A>` where only the elements for which the function returns true are included.

A special case of the map is the flatMap, where you transform each element into multiple elements and then "flatten" the list. Flattening means turning a `List<List<A>>` into a `List<A>`. So `[[1,2,3], [2,3]]` would turn into `[1,2,3,2,3]`

One problem is that your data is not structured in a way that is nice for streams, as you need info from every layer. But I would still argue its more readable

Comment: awesome thanks! and thanks for the explenation. I think i got it now. Appreciated